# How to compute the minimum sensitivity and specificity a classifier needs to estimate a proportion to within some percent error?

Tags: proportion, sensitivity-specificity

I am building a binary classifier. Once classified, the proportion of positive events will be calculated. The predicted proportion is required to be within 10% of the true proportion. In practice, this classifier will be applied to detect proportions in samples ranging from .1% to 100%. How would I determine the minimum sensitivity and specificity of the classifier to achieve less than a 10% error over the entire range of possible proportions?